# ReportViewer - Fixed Page Header and Footer

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio-2010, ado.net

Is there any possible way to fix the page header and footer so that it can be visible while scrolling down and move to another page?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: yes..just to clarify, it was not crystal report.

Comment: i mean to say r u using Report wizard template?

Comment: nope..i created the report from scratch.Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

*Hi*
**You have to click on the column above the header of the report designer. It will select whole column including Table Header, Table Details, Table Footer and click on the property (F4). Change FixedHeader Property to True**

Comment: Hi..thanks for reply! But I want to fix the PAGE HEADER not TABLE HEADER. Is that possible?

Comment: @Therenho did you get the solution?. then share here.i need the same

Answer (score 0):

Here you go!

1. Select an empty portion of the report
2. In the toolbar (File,Edit, View) you will find an option **Report**
3. Select "Add page header" or "Add Page Footer"
4. Place the header/footer contents
5. You can drag to change the height of header or footer accordingly